# Extjs 4.2.1 Scroll to selection in combo drop down list

Tags: javascript, combobox, extjs4.2, dropdownbox

In extjs 4.2.1, there is some problem with combobox. When drop down list appears, i need to scroll to selected value, not only highlight it. So if selected value is on bottom, scroll remains on top anyways.
Here is my code:

```
Ext.define('FpoApp.store.exams.Courses', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'FpoApp.model.Idname',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'php/exams/getCourses.php',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'rows'
        }
    },
    autoLoad: true
});

Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', {
    queryMode: 'local',
    editable: false,
    valueField: 'id',
    displayField: 'name',   
    store: 'exams.Courses' 
});
```

Also, it seems to work in extjs 3.4.0. Just found an example, where it works perfectly, just as i need. [Here](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.4.0/examples/form/combos.html) is example. Looks like basic comboboxes, nothing special. Have no idea what's wrong with 4.2.1. And yes, i'm using mvc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in `Ext JS 4.2.1` version. 
In `Ext JS 4.2.0` version and also in the newest `Ext JS 4.2.2` version the behavior is same as in `Ext js 3.4.0`

Comment: Thanks for response! Any idea how to fix it on 4.2.1?

Comment: Is there a bug report on Sencha site?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue using Ext's 4.2.0 ComboBox. Turns out I was causing the issue by calling `clearFilter()` on my data store after loading data asynchronously.  Removing this method call fixed my issue:

```
myComboBox.store.clearFilter()
```

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-clearFilter

So this isn't a direct answer to your question, but the moral of the story is to look at your Data.Store as closely as your ComboBox.  This would have saved me a few hours of banging my head against the wall :)